# WireMock throwing 404 default error. Cant find JSON with path maybe?

Tags: java, wiremock

This is my code:

```
public class Tests {

private static WireMockServer wireMockServer;
@BeforeClass
public static void myFirstWiremockTest(){
    wireMockServer = new     WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig()
   .usingFilesUnderClasspath("mappings"));
    wireMockServer.start();


    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost";
    RestAssured.port = wireMockServer.port();


}
@Test
public void testWireMockAndRestAssured(){
  given().baseUri("http://localhost")
          .port(wireMockServer.port())
          .when()
          .get("/testEndPoint")
          .then().statusCode(200)
          .body(is("Hey! This is a mock response")).log().all();
}

@AfterClass
public static void teatDown(){
    wireMockServer.stop();
  }
}
```

`

Path to mappings is:
`src/test/resources/mappings/testEndPoint.json`

For some reason I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <404>.
```

I know this is the default error, but why does it happen?

JSON looks like this:

```
 {
   "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/testEndPoint"
   },
  "response":{
     "status": 200,
     "body":"Hey! This is a mock response",
     "headers": {
     "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    }
  }
}
```

I think it should be fine, but it's not. What could be the problem?

Tried checking out the path, checking the json, the code. Thought gonna solve it, but they seem fine.